# Cannot select ngClass element from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive, ng-class

Im using `angularjs` `ng-class` `directive` to add class with `ng-if`, and Im using another modules directive to do something with this element with this class name, but on runtime it's not working directive cannot find the element with this class name, when i hard code the class name its working, but from ng-class injected class name not working.

```
<!-- 'A' not picking by directive -->
<div ng-class="{'myclass': item.isTrue}" ng-repeat="item in vm.list">...</div>

<-- 'B' working -->
<div class="myclass" ng-repeat="item in vm.list">...</div>
```

Directive.

```
var tmp = $element[0].getElementsByClassName("myclass"); // not working with 'A' but fine  with 'B'
```

Comment: Does your `item.IsTrue` return true

Comment: yes compiled code shows the class name

Comment: can you post the entire directive's code?

Comment: this is the directive code on github https://github.com/Poordeveloper/ion-sticky

Answer (score 0):

I guess there's an issue with the `ng-class` of the `directive` call. Also, the directive of type `class` is used less often as one can always the achieve the same with that of the `attribute` and `element`.

I have created a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/28g44nsw/), how one can achieve using the same using `ng-if` my invoking the `directive` of type `attribute` and `class`:

> 1. Using it as *Attribute*

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data">
    <div>
      {{item.name}}
      <span ng-if="item.isTrue" myclass></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

> 2. Using it as *Class*

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data">
    <div>
      {{item.name}}
      <span ng-if="item.isTrue" class="myclass">
      </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The **JS** for both of them is common as below:

```
$scope.data = [{
    'id': 0,
    'name': 'Name 1',
    'isTrue': false
  }, {
    'id': 1,
    'name': 'Name 2',
    'isTrue': true
  }, {
    'id': 2,
    'name': 'Name 3',
    'isTrue': true
  }, {
    'id': 3,
    'name': 'Name 4',
    'isTrue': false
}];
```